# Clear Airflow Tasks on Google Cloud via gcloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I am running Airflow Version : 1.10.15+composer and try to clear tasks via the command line. The following works for the full DAG:

```
gcloud --project my-dev-project composer environments run development --location europe-west1 clear -- -s 2021-04-12 -e 2021-04-14 my_dag
```

However, when using the option -t to select a task, e.g.

```
gcloud --project my-dev-project composer environments run development --location europe-west1 clear -- -s 2021-04-12 -e 2021-04-14 my_dag -t my_task
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/airflow", line 7, in <module>
    exec(compile(f.read(), __file__, 'exec'))
  File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/bin/airflow", line 37, in <module>

...

    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
  File "/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/copy.py", line 169, in deepcopy
    rv = reductor(4)
TypeError: can't pickle _thread.RLock objects
```

Any help appreciated!